# Wordpress SQL query with multiple taxonomies

Tags: sql, wordpress, taxonomy

i am working on a project that displays posts type within a radius entered ordered by the distance from the target address. 
right now i am using this query which works fine:

```
sql = " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wposts.post_id, ( " . $_GET['mikm'] . " *           acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( wposts.lat ) ) * cos( radians( wposts.long ) - radians( $long ) ) + sin( radians( $lat ) ) * sin( radians( wposts.lat) ) ) )  AS distance  
    FROM post_address  wposts 
    WHERE wposts.post_type ='" . $post_type . "'
    HAVING distance <= $radius OR distance IS NULL ORDER BY distance LIMIT " . $from_page . "," . $per_page;
```

post_address is a table that hold posts id, post type, and addresses. when a post being saved or updated with an address this table is being update with the information.
the form i use has fields for address, checkbox to choose mile or kilometers, and distance in a dropdown menu. i use the method get with the form for pagination.

while the query above works fine i am trying to add taxonomies support. i managed to make it work with one taxonomy using

```
wp_dropdown_categories($tax_name)
```

and the SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wposts.post_id, ( " . $_GET['mikm'] . " * acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( wposts.lat ) ) * cos( radians( wposts.long ) - radians( $long ) ) + sin( radians( $lat ) ) * sin( radians( wposts.lat) ) ) )  AS distance  
FROM post_address  wposts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.post_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE wposts.post_type ='" . $post_type . "'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy IN ('" $tax_name "')
AND ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.parent IN (" . $_GET[$tax_name] . ") OR $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN (" . $_GET[$tax_name] . "))
HAVING distance <= $radius OR distance IS NULL ORDER BY distance LIMIT " . $from_page . "," . $per_page;
```

now, since one taxonomy work fine i want to make it work with multiple taxonomies and that is where i get stuck. if for example post type "cars" has 2 taxonomies "model" and "color" i want to be able to filted posts that has "this" model and "this" color. i do not know how many taxonomies exist for the post type(who ever going to use this plugin will enter it manually in admin settings) and they right now being saved in array. for example
$taxonomies = array('car_model','car_color') and i can populate the categories dropdown using:

```
`
foreach ($taxonomies as $tax) {
echo     '<div id="' . $tax . '_cat">';
echo       '<label for="category-id">Choose category: </label>';
        custom_taxonomy_dropdown($tax); 
echo     '</div>';    
`
```

and

```
function custom_taxonomy_dropdown($tax_name) {
$args = array(
        'taxonomy'          => $tax_name,
        'hide_empty'        => 0,
        'depth'             => 10,
        'hierarchical'      =>  1,
        'id'                =>  $tax_name . '_id',
        'name'              => $tax_name,
        'selected'          => $_GET[$tax_name],
        'show_option_all'   => 'All categories',
        );      
wp_dropdown_categories($args); 
}
```

the dropdowns works fine and the output being sent to url as well but i cant find out the SQL query that will make it work.

this is my first project. excuse me if this question is way to long but i was trying to as clear as i can. i also not sure if any of the code above are the best way to go but any help from anyone would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

below is the code i am using now and it works with multiple taxonomies. however, i still get into some issues. when i am choosing "all categories" in all of the taxonomies the sql will look like:

```
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ()
```

and the count will show count(*) = 0 which bring no results instead of all results.

other issue is with child and grandchild categories. when i choose the parent category i expect to get results of all its child and grandchild categories. but since no post is attached to the parent but to its child categories i get no results. 
this is my code now:

```
    "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wposts.post_id, (" . $_GET['mikm'] . "* acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( wposts.lat ) ) * cos( radians( wposts.long ) - radians( $long ) ) + sin( radians( $lat ) ) * sin( radians( wposts.lat) ) ) )  AS distance 
        FROM posts_address  wposts
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.post_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE 
    wposts.post_type IN ('" . $post_type . "')

    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN (" . $total_terms .") 
    GROUP BY wposts.post_id, wposts.lat, wposts.long        
        HAVING count(*) = " . $bc . " AND distance <= $radius OR distance IS NULL ORDER BY distance LIMIT " . $from_page . "," . $per_page  ;
```

any help is appriciated.

Comment: This behavior probably means that, for wordpress, selecting no category means selecting all categories. This poses a problem, because the approach I described needs to know how many categories are there. I'd test for the case of no category selected, and change the query parameters, in the PHP code, to be a list of all taxonomy categories (i.e. getting rid of the empty category least meaning "all categories")

Comment: s/empty category least/empty category list/

Comment: that is what i am doing right now. i am trying to create a case when no category chooses . for child and grandchild categories i am tweaking the code a little. i have to run foreach loop with get_term_children() to check if the term i choose is a parent and if so get its children ids. then i use those ids to run the sql. else it will run the term i choose. i am getting there. thanks again. that was a great welcome to this community. you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your requirements correctly, you don't need to extract information on the taxonomy from the database, only verify that a post "joins" all required taxonomies. Join posts with all required taxonomies, then filter based on the line multiplication result.

First step, where you have

```
$wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy IN ('" $tax_name "')
```

and

```
$wpdb->term_taxonomy.parent IN (" . $_GET[$tax_name] . ") OR $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN (" . $_GET[$tax_name] . "))
```

have it so that the arguments that go into the IN operator produce a list of all the taxonomy names, comma separated, surrounded by quotes. e.g:

```
$wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy IN ('model_a', 'color_blue')
```

Now, the query will multiply posts with all of the taxonomies (in your filter) that the post matches. From here on, it's simple: group by the post fields (you need only group by the ones you output in the query), and filter using HAVING so that you return only posts multiplied by all categories. In this example, the post should have matched two categories, so:

```
(...)
GROUP BY wposts.post_id, wposts.lat, wposts.long
HAVING count(*) = 2 AND (distance <= $radius OR distance IS NULL ORDER BY distance LIMIT " . $from_page . "," . $per_page);
```

Note that the count(*) filter should match the number of taxonomy "axes" matched. Also note that I'm assuming there are no collisions in taxonomies (i.e. There is no "blue" model and "blue" color).

You should probably remove the DISTINCT operator in the query (grouping already produces distinct posts, and I'm not sure when will mysql's optimizer calculate the distinct operator).

Comment: Thank you Sergio, i tried you solution but i couldn't make it work. i think that where you suggested to enter the taxonomies $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy ('model_a', 'color_blue') IN it should be term_taxonomy.term_id IN with the terms id that i picked from the dropdowns. and in that case i will get posts with either the model i choose or the color i choose. when i need only the posts that has the model and the color i choose.

Comment: You are halfway there. Try the query without grouping, and you should get all post,taxonomy pairs. Then, if you group by the post fields and produce a count(*) you should get posts and how many of the taxonomies did it match. Then, add the count(*) condition in the HAVING clause, and you can filter for posts that match ALL the required taxonomies.

Comment: thank you so much, it did work this time. i didn't get result the first time i tried because of the brackets in the "AND (distance...)". after i removed them it worked. however, i still get into some other issues now  . i updated my question with the code i am using now and with the issues i have. any additional information about the those issues will be very helpful for me. i am still marking you answer as the right answer since it solved my original question. thank you.